# Nutch-Cygwin How to set JAVA_HOME

Tags: cygwin, nutch

i am trying to run Nutch with Cygwin. I am having problems setting the JAVA_HOME.

```
 $ export JAVA_HOME='/cygdrive/f/program files/java/jdk1.6.0_21'
```

When i run nutch command

```
$ bin/nutch crawl
```

i get

```
cygpath: can't convert empty path
bin/nutch: line 268: /cygdrive/f/program: No such file or directory
bin/nutch: line 268: exec: /cygdrive/f/program: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

It appears that the space between program and files causes the problem `/cygdrive/f/**program files**/java/jdk1.6.0_21`

Is there a way that i can escape the space? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

**EDIT**

At the end of the day, i had to re-install java in another directory with no space in its name.

Comment: You can use DOS style path: export JAVA_HOME='c:/PROGRA~1/Java/..." Works for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use double quotes in:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/f/program files/java/jdk1.6.0_21"
```

and wherever the script uses the JAVA_HOME variable, for example:

```
JAVA="$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java
```

Regards