# Javadoc generation for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classpath, javadoc

I am trying to generate my documentation for my android project with javadoc. The problem is that javadoc isn't able to find the android package. My error is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200234/javadoc-in-eclipse-failing-to-recognize-packages) one. If I am trying the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5200473/1754625) solution it says:

> javadoc: error - The -classpath option may be specified no more than once.

What am I doing wrong?

Furthermore, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8182949/1754625) solution, but I dont know what I have to do at the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8182949/1754625) solution. All I needed to do is to install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html). After it was installed, I needed to install [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) on Cygwin like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3858799/1754625). Afterwards, I had to [configure java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346510/1754625) in Cygwin.

And now a new detail for me(maybe the reason why the `-classpath` command didn't worked for me in the third step of Generate Javadoc in Eclipse). I had to open the **javadoc.xml** and saw this line:

```
<javadoc [...] additionalparam="-classpath C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar" classpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar" [...]/>
```

The additionalparam is my own of the third step of Generate Javadoc. I took that path and put it into the classpath="" ... That's it. Maybe someone could say how to configure the classpath in Eclipse manually, because I couldn't find something.

Allright, now switched to the folder of the `javadoc.sh` and run that file with `sh javadoc.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I've found you can add multiple paths to -classpath by separating them with semi-colons and enclosing the whole in quotes (in case of spaces in paths)

```
-classpath ".;c:\full\path\to\another\codebase\java;C:\path\to\android.jar"
```